# Disappearing plot (All values has been filtered away)

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to get the following plot to work

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[%
scale only axis,
xmin=0, xmax=14,
xlabel={Iterations},
ymin=-0.747366157054232, ymax=-0.627152206833444,
yminorticks=true,
ylabel={Values $g(x)$}
]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid
]
table{
1 -0.627152206833444
2 -0.727653418778865
3 -0.744147940956529
4 -0.74683810473197
5 -0.747279463520111
6 -0.747351895087422
7 -0.747363807639291
8 -0.747365769422513
9 -0.747366093009514
10 -0.747366146462357
11 -0.747366155305526
12 -0.747366156770711
13 -0.747366157013831
14 -0.747366157054232
};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

The problem is that i obtain the error message

> ! Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (or
>   all have be en filtered away)

I assume it has to do with the combination of very close values, and logarithmic scales. (The plot compiles just fine using normal axis)

Is there any method to get the plot to work *with* a logarithmic scale? 
'
Nw

Comment: This happens because you only have negative y-values in your plot, and the logarithm isn't defined for negative values. You could reverse the sign of your data to make the logarithmic plot work, but with this dataset, the plot wouldn't get any clearer (the values near the asymptote would just get pushed closer together).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because you only have negative y-values in your plot, and the logarithm isn't defined for negative values. You could reverse the sign of your data to make the logarithmic plot work, but with this dataset, the plot wouldn't get any clearer (the values near the asymptote would just get pushed closer together).